# Calculate the volume of $T = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 : 0 \leq z \leq x^2 + y^2, (x-1)^2 + y^2 \leq 1, y \geq 0\}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

> Calculate the volume of $T = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 : 0 \leq z \leq x^2 + y^2, (x-1)^2 + y^2 \leq 1, y \geq 0\}$

so I said that the integral we need is $\iint_{D} {x^2 + y^2 dxdy}$.
But when I drew $D$ I got this:
[image]

Now I said I want to move the circle to the middle so I would have its' center at $(0,0)$ so I did a change of variables where :

$$\begin{array}{11} x=u+1 \\ v = y\\ J(u,v) = 1 \\ u=r\cos\theta\\v=r\sin\theta\\0 \leq r \leq 1 \\ 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi  \end{array}$$

And we need $\iint_{D} {u^2 + 2u + 1 + v dudv}$

And the integral we finally need to calculate is:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} {d\theta {\int_{0}^{1} r^2\cos\theta + 2r\cos\theta + 1 + r\sin\theta du dv}} = 1 + \pi$$ but wolfram does not agree with my answer.
What went wrong?

Comment: Your integrand should be $(u+1)^2+v^2$

Alternatively, you can represent the volume as such:
$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2cos{\theta}} \int_0^{r^2} rdzdrd\theta$

Comment: Oh you're correct, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can advance this way, we change to polar as

$$ (x-1)^2+y^2=1 \implies x^2+y^2=2x \implies r=2\cos(\theta),\quad 0\leq \theta \leq \pi/2 .$$

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{2\cos(\theta)} r^2 \,rdrd\theta = \frac{3}{4}\pi. $$

Comment: Oh now I see where my mistake is!
Thanks.
I got $\frac{3\pi}{4}$. Have you got the same?

Comment: @TheNotMe: Let me check.

Comment: @TheNotMe: Yes that's correct.

Comment: Much appreciated. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @TheNotMe: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted to square y, and maybe also change $dudv$ to $rdrd\theta$.
It might be easier to use that the equation of the original circle is $r=2\cos\theta$, and that $\theta$ varies from 0 to $\pi/2$.